# const correctness and member pointers

Tags: c++, constants, const-correctness

I have const on the Accelerate method, yet I can call the power method. Is their a way to actually stop this.

```
class Engine{
public:
    void Power(){
    }
};

class Car{
public:
    Car() : p(new Engine()){}

    void Accelerator() const{
        p->Power();
    } 
    private:
        Engine* p;
};
```

Comment: Because your `Engine` pointer is `const` and not the thing that it points to.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need a `Engine*` instead of just a `Engine`?

Comment: A real car would contain the engine, and not only point to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Car`, a const method is a methods which does not modify `Car` member variables.

so, as long that `Car::Accelerator` does not make `p` point to a different location, it is valid.

since `p` is not modified in `Accelerator` (meaning it does not point to a different memory address), the program is valid.

the moment you make `p` point to a different location, the program fails to compile:

```
  void Accelerator() const {
        p= nullptr; //wrong
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Const protection affects only the direct members, in this case the pointer only. Values outside this object (aka. pointed values) are not protected.

You have to decide if you consider the pointed value as yourself or someone else.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the member `Engine` as `const*`, which will make the `Engine` object pointed to by `p` in `Car` `const`:

```
class Engine{
 public:
  void Power(){
  }
};

class Car{
 public:
  Car() : p(new Engine()){}

  void Accelerator() const{
      p->Power();
  } 
 private:
  Engine const* p;
};
```

This will no longer compile:

```
test_const.cpp:12:9: error: member function 'Power' not viable: 'this' argument
      has type 'const Engine', but function is not marked const
        p->Power();
        ^
test_const.cpp:3:10: note: 'Power' declared here
    void Power(){
         ^
```

But this implies that no member of `Car` can modify `*p`, which is probably not what you intend. See @NathanOliver's comment for better answer.

Hope this helps.